# Solving an easy inequality

Tags: inequality

Please, help me to solve the inequality:
$$\sqrt{x^2+2x} > -3-x^2$$

I think I solved it, could you check it, guys?[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: By definition square roots are always positive. What is the right-hand-side of your inequality?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: the LHS is nonnegative whereas the RHS is negative, so you only need to find $x$ such that $\sqrt{x^2+2x}=\sqrt{x(x+2)}$ is well-defined.